# ASP.NET MVC ActionMethodSelector dependency injection/replacement

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I wish to replace the implementation of `System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodSelector` as used by the `FindAction` method of `ReflectedControllerDescriptor`, but would like to take advantage of the existing implementation, ideally by deriving from `ActionMethodSelector`. However, because the class is marked as internal the only way I can see to do this 'properly' is to derive from `ReflectedControllerDescriptor` and implement `FindAction` by copying the code from `ActionMethodSelector`. I wish to avoid this however due to the quantity of code, and potential issues trying to keep it up to date with the framework.

I'm considering the following approaches:

1. Biting the bullet and copying the code
2. Using reflection so as to take advantage of the existing implementation

Are there any other approaches that I'm missing, better or otherwise?

Comment: Are you referring to the ActionMethodSelectorAttribute class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionmethodselectorattribute(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: @PaulTaylor No, to the internal class System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodSelector: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/ActionMethodSelector.cs

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late to answer still I am giving it a try.... :)

I believe that you somehow want to tweak action method selection process in ASP.NET MVC. If my understanding is correct you can make use of custom ActionMethodSelectorAttribute by deriving from System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodSelectorAttribute. Write your own custom logic in the custom selector and apply it on the top of the action methods. I believe in this way the action method selection process can be tweaked without disturbing the natural process.

If you wish you can visit these links: http://programersnotebook.blogspot.in/2014/02/aspnet-mvc-actionnameselector-and.html, http://programersnotebook.blogspot.in/2014/02/aspnet-mvc-actionnameselector-and_2.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I need to somehow choose a preferred action method amongst the list of possible action methods, i.e. given action A and action B, which are both valid candidates, choose action A because of some condition. I can't see any way of using the ActionMethodSelectorAttribute to achieve this without duplicating a lot of code. Thanks for giving me a new avenue to investigate though :)

Comment: I believe if the parameters - on which you want to build your conditions- can be made a part of the the request, then the ActionMethodSelector can be somehow used.In the action method selector you can play with request in any way you deem fit and tweak the selection process of the action method. I may help you better if you can share the specific requirements and how you want to implement those.

Comment: I want to prefer actions declared in derived classes to enable easy overriding of actions which also change the method signature. Currently my team has to override the original method, decorate it with `NonAction`, and then implement the replacement method. To implement this I need to know the entire list of candidate methods, and discard ones declared in superclasses. I can't see any easy way of doing this with `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute`.